# Accessing Android/iPhone volume buttons with HTML5 app

Tags: android, html, ios

Does anyone know if there is a way to access to the volume button events in an HTML5 application run on the phone's browser?

Comment: Have you tried with the idea of remmaping its triggering to [something else](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.irishin.buttonsremapper&hl=en)?
My curiosity brougth me here. Maybe it can be able to send the pressing of a ridiculously useless key and then activate something else in your html creature.

Comment: Hey! have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: unfortunately the onvolumechange event of HTML5 <audio> and <video> doesn't trigger when using the volume keys of your phone :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that it's impossible to have access to the volume buttons with HTML5 on the phone's browser.

One's has to use the native APIs (either Android or iOS).